# How to remove (...) from the post tilte on homepage?

Tags: customization

[image: want to remove ... in title]Please help. I want to remove ... from the post title below the thumbnail in homepage.

Comment: Hi Charlie! This is probably controlled by your theme. You may want to look in some of the theme files such as index.php which renders your home page to see if you can see code for printing out the post title.

Comment: It could be simply `ellipsis`. Are you good at css? if yes then try adding `text-overflow: initial;` to your title class.